# Как проверить текущую Activity в UI тесте

Tags: android, test-automation, espresso

Для тестов я использую Espresso и Barista
У меня есть тест в котором мне надо открыть другой экран по нажатию на кнопку. Как я могу проверить открылся ли этот экран? Открылся ли нужный мне экран?

Можно ли как-то проверить цепочку экранов? Чтоб понять, что экраны открываются в нужном мне порядке?

Если кто-то скинет ссылки на хорошие туториалы по UI тестам в Android буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот код поможет вам получить инстанс текущей активити

```
   private fun getActivityInstance(): Activity? {
        val currentActivity = arrayOf<Activity?>(null)
        getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(Runnable {
            val resumedActivity: Collection<Activity> =
                ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance()
                    .getActivitiesInStage(Stage.RESUMED)
            val it = resumedActivity.iterator()
            currentActivity[0] = it.next()
        })
        return currentActivity[0]
   }
```